# Cannot find the child_model - rescue in child_model

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I'm getting the below error with the following models. I'm at a loss as to why.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

`Cannot find the child_model Document for Event in documents
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/associations/relationship.rb:173:in 'rescue in child_model'`

Document Model:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class Document
  include DataMapper::Resource
  include Paperclip::Resource

  timestamps :at

  property :id,                 Serial
  property :name,               String, :required => true
  property :doc_file_name,      String, :length => 255
  property :doc_content_type,   String, :length => 255
  property :doc_file_size,      Integer
  property :doc_updated_at,      DateTime
  has_attached_file :doc, :url => "/doc/:attachment/:id/:basename.:extension", :path => "#{settings.root}/public/doc/:attachment/:id/:basename.:extension"

  belongs_to :event

  validates_attachment_presence :doc
end
```

Event Model:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Event
  include DataMapper::Resource
  timestamps :at

  property :id,          Serial
  property :name,        String, :required => true
  property :occuring,    DateTime, :required => true

  has n, :documents
  has n, :contacts
  has n, :users
  has n, :agendas
  has n, :questionnaires
  has n, :entries, :required => false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling `DataMapper.finalize/auto_upgrade`? It sounds like you have some sort of chicken and egg problem. You need to require all your models in one place before you call `finalize` + `auto_upgrade`.

Comment: Currently `Dir.glob(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/models/*') {|file| require file} / DataMapper.finalize / # DataMapper.auto_migrate!` Though, I'm requiring the models before the DataMapper.setup if that makes a difference. After a bit of fooling around, I figured out part of it, but it consisted of removing the Dir glob and replacing it with individual require statements. Maybe dealing with the order dir glob loads files in?

Comment: You have to be careful when requiring with absolute paths, since if you use relative paths elsewhere you will require the same file multiple times. That could possibly cause problems. I.e. `require "models/foo"` + `require "./models/foo"` will require foo two times. Make sure you know where you require and what. Other than that there's not enough information to say much else. Hope you get it working, and if not keep simplifying your code and setup until it works, and then trace back your steps and analyze what it is that causes the bug.